# REVTeX affiliations without superscripts

Tags: titles, revtex, affiliation

I have multiple authors, all with the same affiliations. Is there a way I can get REVTeX to suppress superscripts?

For example, all of these folks will have "1),2)" next to their name:

```
\documentclass[aip,jap,reprint]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\title{My Paper}
\author{First Person}
\email{first@example.com}
\author{Second Person}
\author{Third Person}
\author{Fourth Person}

\affiliation{Some Place}
\affiliation{Different Place}

\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the `groupedaddress` class option of [`revtex4-1`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/revtex4-1), you can suppress the affiliation superscripts in this case:

[image]

```
\documentclass[aip,jap,reprint,groupedaddress]{revtex4-1}

\begin{document}
\title{My Paper}
\author{First Person}
\email{first@example.com}
\author{Second Person}
\author{Third Person}
\author{Fourth Person}

\affiliation{Some Place}
\affiliation{Different Place}

\maketitle
\end{document}​
```

Other options and author/affiliation displays are also available. See section **IV.3 Specifying author and affiliations** (p 6) of the [`revtex4-1` documentation](https://authors.aps.org/revtex4/auguide4-1.pdf).

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Is there a way to suppress the "and" that appears between "Some Place" and "Different Place"? I suppose I could always do \affiliation{Some Place\\Different Place}...

Comment: @user825518: That is one option. You may have to work some magic if the alignment is off.